# Date on confirmation email

Tags: email, date, if-statement

I am trying to put the date of delivery on our confirmation email. 
Due to the different shipping options I would like the email to say 'Estimated Delivery Date' if they choose the Standard FREE Delivery and if choose the other options then the email to say 'Delivery Date'. Below is the code that I tried to use but it did not work

```
You've chosen: {{ shipping_method.title }}   
{%if shipping_method.title == Standard FREE Delivery%} Est Delivery Date {{ attributes.date }}  {% endif %} 
{% if shipping_method.title != Standard FREE Delivery %} Delivery Date {{ attributes.date }} {% endif %}
```

Comment: A. What is this? What environment, language.. ? B. What didn't work? C. Read [ask]

Comment: Trying to do in HTML. The shipping_method.title is displayed. But then none of the other bits are shown.

Comment: When I have just the shipping_method.title and {{attributes.date}} both the shipping method and the date are shown. So I'm think have I done the if statement wrong?